# C++11 STL::LIST empty() should lock in multithread situation?

Tags: multithreading, list, c++11, locking, empty-list

In C++, thread 1 only psuh_back(data) in LIST, and thread 2 only pop_front(data) from LIST. Do I need to lock empty() in thread 2? I only worry about the situation where LIST is empty but empty() returns false. Is this worry unnecessary?

```
list<my_strust> buffer;

static void receivedata(my_strust &data)
{
    mutex.lock();
    buffer.push_back(data);
    mutex.unlock();
}
static void senddata()
{
    while(1) {
        if (buffer.empty()) {
            continue;
        }
        mutex.lock();
        buffer.pop_front();
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need a lock around `empty()` call. As written, this example exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race.

Comment: I don`t worry about the situation where LIST is not empty but empty() returns true. 
I only worry about the situation where LIST is empty but empty() returns false.
even so，do I need to lock empty() call?

Comment: Your program contains a data race, and therefore exhibits undefined behavior. You cannot reason about outcomes of a program that contains undefined behavior. You could salvage this approach by maintaining an atomic counter alongside the list, kept in sync with `buffer.size()`. You could check that counter outside the mutex.